# change inline-block container height smooth

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-transitions

https://jsfiddle.net/4a64jso1/1/

.a and .b are inline-block with different height in a container
after click `.a`,
`.a` expand width to 100%, `.b` height to 0,  that means container only can see `.a` and container height will change to `.a` height.

my problem is how to make the container height change not look like flash, bounce  ....  make it smooth ...  ?
I tried to add transition in container too but not work, I think because I don't set container height, but I don't want to set container height.

```js
$('.a').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').addClass('expand');
})
$('.back').on('click', function() {
  $('.container').removeClass('expand');
})
```

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.container >div {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  -webkit-transition: width 0.45s;
  transition: width 0.45s;
}
.b {
  width: 200px;
  height: 1000px;
  max-height: 99999px;
  background-color: red;
  -webkit-transition: max-height 0.45s;
  transition: max-height 0.45s;
}
.container.expand .a {
  width: 100%;
}
.container.expand .b {
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="back">back</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="a">a</div>
  <div class="b">b</div>
</div>
<div class="other">other</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could add `$('.b').slideUp(400);` in your function.

EDIT: and, of course `$('.b').slideDown(400);` to bring it back down.

Comment: you mean animation on .b after .a change width ?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4a64jso1/3/ I make this, a little weird, but better ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

U can use Jquery.animate

```
$( "#a" ).click(function() {
    $( "#b" ).animate({
        height: "100%"
      }, 1000, function() {
        // Animation complete you can do something here aswell.
      });
    });
```

Btw if u want ui bounce or something use:
for animation swing/bounce etc or not.
https://jqueryui.com/

This will explain why you should use it or not ;)
https://www.google.com/design/spec/motion/material-motion.html